# Obtaining Indicial Equation

Tags: differential, frobenius-method

I think my question is pretty simple but I'm struggling to understand how to find indicial equations and would really appreciate some help.

I have this equation:

$$4xy''(x) +2y'(x) + y(x) = 0$$

I want to find the indicial equation.

I started by finding $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ which i believe are $1/2x$ and $1/4x$ respectively.

I believe $ x=0$ is a singular point (i might be wrong).

Where i get stuck is here, I know the next step involves limits, it might be along the lines of something like: $lim(x-0)P(x)$ but I'm really not sure.

If someone could help out and guide me through what I would need to do next that would help a lot. I know this might be quite simple but I'm quite new to this concept and don't really understand it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For finding indicial roots put $y=x^m$ and compare the coefficient of the smallest power of $x$ to zero.
$$4xy''(x) +2y'(x) + y(x) = 0 \implies 4m(m-1)x^{m-1}+2m x^{m-1}+x^m=0$$ $$\implies x^{m-1}(4m^2-2m)+x^m.$$
$m=0,1/2$ are the indicial roots.

Comment: Ok, I sort of get what you did here but could you please go over how you got the $m$'s in the places you did, I understand you substituted $y=x^m$ but I'm just a bit confused with why the $m$'s go where you've put them.

Comment: Set the coefficient of the least power of $x$ to zero. Here between $x^m$ and $x^{m-1}$ it is $x^{m-1}$ and hence $(4m^2-2m)=0$ is the indicial equation.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I have one more question (and I might just be being stupid here) but why do both $y'$ and $y''$ become $x^{m-1}$? I understand why $y'$ becomes this but why does $y''$ become the same thing? Shouldn't it be $x^{m-2}$ since it's the second derivative of $y$?

Comment: It is $4xy'$' and $3y'$ that give you $ x^{m-1}$, check.